# R: rolling ratio of values in each colunm

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I'm looking to get the rolling ratio of values in each column. e.g. 5th/1st, 6th/2nd etc and have the results in a new data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), each = 4),
                 score_1 = 1:16,
                 score_2 = 5:20)
```

With the example data above I want each row (n) (from the 5th down) to be divided by n-4, in this case would create the below table of results.

```
5.0  1.8
3.0  1.7
2.3  1.6
2.0  1.5
1.8  1.4
1.7  1.4
1.6  1.4
1.5  1.3
1.4  1.3
1.4  1.3
1.4  1.3
1.3  1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `head()` and `tail()`:

```r
tail(df, -4)[-1] / head(df, -4)[-1]

# Also
# (\(x, n) tail(x, n) / head(x, n))(df[-1], -4)
#
#     score_1  score_2
# 5  5.000000 1.800000
# 6  3.000000 1.666667
# 7  2.333333 1.571429
# 8  2.000000 1.500000
# 9  1.800000 1.444444
# 10 1.666667 1.400000
# 11 1.571429 1.363636
# 12 1.500000 1.333333
# 13 1.444444 1.307692
# 14 1.400000 1.285714
# 15 1.363636 1.266667
# 16 1.333333 1.250000
```

---

With `dplyr`, you can use `lag()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-Group, ~ .x / lag(.x, 4L)))
```

Comment: Thanks, the `dplyr` solution is the one I have used.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide each original vector with its lagged version like so:

```r
x <- 1:16
x / dplyr::lag(x, n = 4L)
#>  [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA 5.000000 3.000000 2.333333 2.000000
#>  [9] 1.800000 1.666667 1.571429 1.500000 1.444444 1.400000 1.363636 1.333333
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can directly divide the dataframe with the subset of it.

```
df[5:nrow(df), 2:3]/df[(5:nrow(df)) - 4, 2:3]

    score_1  score_2
5  5.000000 1.800000
6  3.000000 1.666667
7  2.333333 1.571429
8  2.000000 1.500000
9  1.800000 1.444444
10 1.666667 1.400000
11 1.571429 1.363636
12 1.500000 1.333333
13 1.444444 1.307692
14 1.400000 1.285714
15 1.363636 1.266667
16 1.333333 1.250000
```